# Разделить код на разные файлы

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте, у меня код цельный, можно свойства объекта ball вынести в отдельный файл? и как их связать? (мне нужно будет использовать ball в нескольких файлах)
https://yadi.sk/d/MjdwSnm4uDwas

```html
`let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
        let tex = self.view?.textureFromNode(ball)
        var ballk = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex)
        
        textureAtlasBall = SKTextureAtlas(named: "myball")
        for i in 1...textureAtlasBall.textureNames.count{
            let nameBall = "ball_\(i).png"
            textureArrayBall.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: nameBall))
        }
        ballk = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: textureAtlasBall.textureNames[0])
        ballk.size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        let animationWithTextureBall = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textureArrayBall, timePerFrame: 0.2)
        let repeatActionForeverBall = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animationWithTextureBall)
        ballk.runAction(repeatActionForeverBall)
        ballk.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.size.width - 320, y: scene!.size.height - 255)
        ballk.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 12)
        ballk.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball1
        ballk.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Border | PhysicsCategory.Ball1 | PhysicsCategory.Kvadr | PhysicsCategory.Ball2  | PhysicsCategory.Ball3  | PhysicsCategory.Ball4
        ballk.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Square
        self.addChild(ballk)
        self.ballReference = ballk
        ballk.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте файл Ball.swift:

```
class Ball: SKShapeNode {

    init(circleOfRadius: CGFloat, position: CGPoint){
        super.init()

        let diameter = circleOfRadius * 2
        self.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: diameter, height: diameter)), nil)
        self.strokeColor = SKColor.brownColor()
        self.fillColor = SKColor.grayColor()
        self.position = position
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

и используйте в GameScene.swift так:

```
func ballStop(){
    let position = CGPoint(x: scene!.size.width - 50, y: scene!.size.height - 50)
    let ball = Ball(circleOfRadius: 25, position: position)
    self.addChild(ball)
    self.ballReference = ball
}
```

Если нужны какие-то дополнительные свойства Ball, добавьте.

Comment: А можете пояснить насчет  init() как понять что именно в скобках прописывать?

Comment: `super.init()`? Ничего. Это инициализация `SKShapeNode`.

Comment: можно еще вопрос? если добавить текстуру в свойства, то как это прописать?
(код добавила вверх в вопрос)

Comment: Аналогичным образом создать подкласс класса `SKSpriteNode`

Comment: разобралась, спасибо за помощь)